# reading parameters from command line arguments

Tags: c, cmd

What I want to do is to get parameter from cmd line arguments, like that: 12/24/2000, and store them into int mm, int d, int yyyy; It could print out correctly, but shows me wrong value, when I pass them into a function.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int x, y, d, mm, yyyy;
    char* a = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    a = argv[1];
    x = getDateKey(9, 27, 2022);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d/%d/%d", &d, &mm, &yyyy);
    y = getDateKey(d, mm, yyyy);
    printf("%d\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

What print is when I execute (myprogram 9/27/2022):

```
270 (correct)
-118647133
```

EDIT code of getDateKey:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lab4.h"

int getDateKey(int month, int day, int year) {
        int i, key, check = 0;
        if(isLeap(year)){
                check = 1;
        }
        for(i = 1; i < month; i++) {
                if(i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 7 || i == 8 || i == 10 || i == 12) {
                        key += 31;
                } else if(i == 2) {
                        if(check) {
                                key += 29;
                        } else {
                                key += 28;
                        }
                } else {
                        key += 30;
                }
        }
        return key += day;
}
```

Comment: `char *a = malloc ...; a = argv[1];` is a blatant memory leak. It's no different than `int x = 5; x = 7;`. (Except that `malloc` has the side effect of allocating memory which your program just lost all access to.)

Comment: If you are truly passing the first argument as `9/27/2022`, it would seem that your program ought to work.  Perhaps `getDateKey` is causing undefined behavior.  Either show the code for that, or remove it entirely from the question.

Comment: `key` is not initialized.  You have undefined behavior.  Initialize it to 0.

Comment: [Relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1179/).

Answer (score 2):

A simple example using `sscanf` to parse the argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x, y, d, mm, yyyy;
    if( argc > 1 && 3 == sscanf(argv[1], "%2d/%2d/%4d", &d, &mm, &yyyy) ){
        printf("%d %d %d\n", d, mm, yyyy);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would guess you are having issues because your argument does not match the format string, but your program doesn't check the value returned by `sscanf` to determine whether or not it successfully read any values into `d`, `mm`, and `yyyy`.  Since the variables `d`, `mm`, and `yyyy` are not initialized, your program invokes undefined behavior if `sscanf` does not write to them.  If it does not write values, then it will return a values less than 3, and your program should catch that condition.  Also, your program does not check if `argc > 1` or if `argv[1] != NULL`, so you have potential undefined behavior even before you pass uninitialized variables to `getDateKey`.

In short, validate the input.

Answer (score 0):

In `getDataKey` you never initialize the variable `key`. The first time you call the function, the value stored at location `key` may by pure luck (or unluck) have the initial value of zero, and the function has the illusion of working as expected